Python/dpkg error
I connect through ssh to an Ubuntu-2204-jammy-amd64-base server and when trying to install, unistall, or do anything related to python I get an error message, i messed around with some python files abit ago which is most likely the issue but nothing i try works to fix it
I did
apt-get install pip3

and get this as an output
Setting up python3-minimal (3.10.6-1~22.04.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-minimal.postinst: 5: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-minimal (--configure):
 installed python3-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-minimal
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


Are you using a third party repository to provide python software to your server?  If you've messed with the system installed python in any way you're likely to be doing things that break installing software like you see here

Not sure, but i know that python itself was installed from mirror.hetzner.com/packages afaik

Im pretty new to this so if you need me to provide more info i can

any way to fix it tho cus I have no idea what I'm doing as I said before

In case you replaced the system python with a different version, you will have to reinstall. In case you did not, try sudo apt update followed by sudo apt install python3

i messed around with some python files abit ago - We don't know what exactly you did, but you have to undo those changes, or reinstall. Many of Ubuntu's necessary processes (including apt) depend on python, and it just would not work if python is not working properly
